# Rails Checkbox formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm trying to build out a survey with a rails app. My rails application has two models: Question has_many :answers and Answer belongs_to :question

I'm trying to iterated through all the questions and all their associated answers and make a checkbox option on all the answers for that associated question. How would I go about making checkboxes? Here's what I have so far. Would this need to be wrapped in a Form for each question too?

```
 <% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= question.content %></td><br>
    <% question.answers.each do |answer_choice| %>
         <%= form.check_box :answer_choice %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to create a nested form for each answer within the question form. You can do it like this:

In `Question.rb` set `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class Question< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
```

Then you can make a form something like this:

```
 <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= form_for @question do |f|
       <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer_builder| %>
           <%= answer_builder.check_box :answer_choice %>
       <%end%>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <%end%>
 <% end %>
```

Now the answer models will automatically be updated when you submit the question form. If you have a `question_params` method in your controller make sure to set it to allow parameters for answers as well, e.g.,:

```
def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:question_name, answers_attributes: [:answer_choice])
end
```

Ryan Bates has an excellent Railscast on nested forms. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1